# Not able to crop image in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop

I have to choose image either from Gallery or capture from Camera, I want to crop image which I have got,

So, I am using following code to call crop intent,

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
//indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
//set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
//retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
 try {
      startActivityForResult(cropIntent, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_CROP_DONE);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException actionNotFoundException) {
      Log.e(TAG, actionNotFoundException.getMessage(), actionNotFoundException);
      Toast.makeText(fragment.getActivity(), fragment.getResources().getString(R.string.crop_not_available), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I am using Nexus 6p device and seems only on this device I am facing this issue.

This gives me Toast message saying that Can not crop image below 50 x 50.

May I know What I am missing?

Comment: please check this blog: https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `com.android.camera.action.CROP` intent doesn't work on all devices, you should use libraries for croping

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether u can crop image just by passing crop intent!!

The error says U are selecting an image that has width x height that is less than 50x50

Try **selecting a larger image** for cropping to work.

PS: Try Using this library for cropping [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)